# tf.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model error on initializing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multi-gpu

I am using python 3 with tensorflow and multiple gpu configuration, I try to use the [following example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model) to init the multi gpu model, I create a model, It's fine, compiling, running and training, but When I try to add this before the model compilation:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2, cpu_merge=False)
```

I get this error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'TensorShape'

Note I am using tf with eager eval

I found [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11408) referring to use keras.utils.multi_gpu_model instead of tf.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model But when I do that I get this error instead:

What am i missing here?

> line 217, in multi_gpu_model
>       with tf.device(x.device): AttributeError: 'DeferredTensor' object has no attribute 'device'

the code for the model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"))
```

update: could this be a gpu id issue? when I try to create a multi_gpu_model without specifing the gpus count with the following code:

```
model = multi_gpu_model(model)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: To call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus=3`, we expect the
>   following devices to be available: ['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1',
>   '/gpu:2']. However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0', '/xla_cpu:0',
>   '/xla_gpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1']. Try reducing `gpus`

I only have 2 gpus, they are connected to pci ports # 1 and 2 (I cant change that, I don't have the proper space on the board needed to connect them to port 0), does it make any sense that when specifying 2 GPUs, tf will try to get GPU 0 and GPU 1? Can I specify otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: Where's your actual model? By the looks of it you don't have a model you've just tried to initialise multi_gpu_model, which coincidentally is also named model...?

Comment: I have a working model, the model is not the issue (it is working without the multi gpu part) but I will add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I met the same mistake, I solved it by changing `os.environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES]='1, 3'` to `os.environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES]="1, 3"`
If you've already done this, you might want to check with this extremly simple code: DO NOT forget to change the gpu device to yours.

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D
import os
#if you have gpu 1,3 avaliable
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1,3"
x = Input((64,64,3))
out = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(x)
model = Model(x,out)
#model = deeplabv3_nopadding.Deeplabv3()
model = multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=2)
```

which will output:

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2019-07-01 09:40:25.971722: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA 2019-07-01 09:40:26.277398: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582 pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0 totalMemory:
>   11.90GiB freeMemory: 11.74GiB 2019-07-01 09:40:26.586391: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 1
>   with properties:  name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582 pciBusID: 0000:83:00.0 totalMemory:
>   11.90GiB freeMemory: 11.74GiB 2019-07-01 09:40:26.586477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0, 1 2019-07-01 09:40:27.377910: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-07-01
>   09:40:27.377970: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 1 
>   2019-07-01 09:40:27.377977: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N N 
>   2019-07-01 09:40:27.377981: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1:   N N 
>   2019-07-01 09:40:27.378592: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   11355 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus
>   id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 2019-07-01 09:40:27.382844:
>   I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with
>   11355 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus
>   id: 0000:83:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)